# How to use wget on a page with authentication

Tags: linux, curl, lua, wget

I've been searching the internet about wget, and found many posts on how to use wget to log into a site that has a login page. 
The site uses https, and the form fields the login page looks for is "userid" and "password".  I've verified this by checking the Network tool in Chrome when you hit F12.

I 've been using the following posts as guidelines:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/131020-using-wget-curl-http-post-authentication.html

And

[wget with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)

**What I've tried:**

```
testlab:/lua_curl_tests# wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'userid=myid&password=123123' https://10.123.11.22/cgi-bin/acd/myapp/controller/method1
wget: unrecognized option `--save-cookies'
BusyBox v1.21.1 (2013-07-05 16:54:31 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

And also

```
testlab/lua_curl_tests# wget
http://userid=myid:123123@10.123.11.22/cgi-bin/acd/myapp/controller/method1
Connecting to 10.123.11.22 (10.123.11.22:80) wget: server returned
error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Ultimately, what I'd like to do is login, and post data, then grab the resulting page. 
I'm also currently looking at curl - to see if I really should be doing this with curl (lua-curl)

Comment: Can you check what version of wget you are using? run `wget -V` and check. `--save-cookies` is a valid wget switch, if it doesn't work, I'd guess the problem lies in busybox maybe.

Comment: lol.  that gives me an error too re - in! but i can see that the busybox version is v1.21.1